# Parse XML Namespace using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prj:Flow xmlns:prj="url1" xmlns:com="url2" xmlns:ns2="url3" xmlns:con="url4" xmlns:ns0="url5" xmlns:ns1="url6" xmlns:ns3="url7">
<prj:str>
<prj:layout comp="abcd">
  <prj:prop>
     <prj:property name="Hardik" value="5000"/>
     <prj:property name="Vipul" value="YES"/>
  </prj:prop>
</prj:layout>
</prj:str>
</prj:Flow>
```

And this what I tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'sample.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('prj\\:prop').each(function() {
          var $entry = $(this);
        var pic = $entry.find('prj\\:property').each(function(){
        var names = $(this).attr('name');
          alert(names);
          })
        })
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      if (xhr.status != 404) {alert(error);} else {alert("404 xml not found");}
  }
});
})
```

I am unable to retrieve the attributes from within the xml namespaces. I also tried the `.find('[nodename=prj:prop]');` style of doing it and still get no result. Am I missing something very basic over here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your Ajax code, not the XML-parsing code. This works fine for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-I1nTg78tSrZev3kjvfdM5A5Ak/blglGzlaZANLPDl3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <prj:Flow xmlns:prj="url1" xmlns:com="url2" xmlns:ns2="url3" xmlns:con="url4" xmlns:ns0="url5" xmlns:ns1="url6" xmlns:ns3="url7"> <prj:str> <prj:layout comp="abcd"> <prj:prop> <prj:property name="Hardik" value="5000"/> <prj:property name="Vipul" value="YES"/> </prj:prop> </prj:layout> </prj:str> </prj:Flow>';
  $(xml).find('prj\\:prop').each(function() {
    console.log("A");
    var $entry = $(this);
    var pic = $entry.find('prj\\:property').each(function() {
      console.log("B");
      var names = $(this).attr('name');
      console.log(names);
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
hi
</body>
</html>
```

So I would make sure your `xml` variable has what you think it has.

Comment: oh ! That is weird. I did look at the syntax and that is exactly how an xml file is loaded using Ajax. I will look for other references. Thank you :)

Comment: I tried to print the xml after loading it through Ajax and it does print the right xml. I still don't know why it isn't giving me the attributes this way. I think it is unable to enter into the Success/ Error functions. Any reason why ?

Comment: Fixed this. I had to change the syntax to look like this for it to work -
find('prj\\:property,property')